# How can i implement single-click-copy functionality in sweet alert in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I  have a sweet alert in one of my react component which displays an Id(ex:Student Id) from an API. Right now, i am able to display the Id in the sweet alert with some message. But i have to make the id as single-click-copy. Please help me with this.

Ex: Student Id is std123.
 I want to make this std123 as single click copy.

Comment: Please share your code. What have you tried so far? [Guide on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: html={ "Student ID" +(<SingleClickCopy copyText = {(this.state.studentId)}/>)}            I am adding singleclick copy component to the html property of the sweetalert